# Node.js Mongo DB find query works weirdly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js MongoDB native driver for this.

When I use condition directly in the find() it Works fine

```
db.collection('test').find({'age':'25'}).toArray().then((docs)=>{
```

When I assign condition to a variable and use it in find() it works fine.

```
var query = {'age':'25'};

db.collection('test').find(query).toArray().then((docs)=>{
```

But when I assign a value from input by user the query doesn't work as expected instead works as if no condition was specified.

```
var query = (`{'age':'${age}'}`)

db.collection('test').find(query).toArray().then((docs)=>{
```

I tried printing the query and I see it has the required condition `{'age':'25'}`

Any thoughts please help.

Comment: Just for debugging, can you try `.find(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(query))`? In your console you may see it as a string while its actually an integer. The best way is to add `.catch(e=>console.log(e))` and give me the error you get

Comment: I don't see any error it works like no condition is specified. returns all docs

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = {'age': `${age}`}
```

Comment: For some reason the ` ` disappeared from the question. I actually have it in code